# How to create index search in CouchDB?

Tags: search, couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant, nosql

Assuming configuring couchDB locally, how and where to create the search index similarly to Cloudant on Bluemix?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I was searching for for was based on [this library](http://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene).

1. I had to install CouchDB 1.6.1 to have available database on http://localhost:5984,
2. the next step was to install couchdb-lucene, which was running on http://localhost:5985 with successfull response. It is maven based app.

> {"couchdb-lucene":"Welcome","version":"1.1.0-SNAPSHOT"}

To make it run I had to build it in the root directory with mvn and then navigate to target and run command **./bin/run** in the unzipped couchdb-lucene:

```
root@mario-VirtualBox:/home/mario/CouchDB_mario/couchdb-lucene/target/couchdb-lucene-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT# ./bin/run
```

3. The next constraint was to connect these two servers together. And all I had to do was to map them via proxy in the **/etc/couchdb/local.ini**

All what you need to have there is the following piece of code:

```
[httpd_global_handlers]
_fti = {couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://localhost:5985">>}
```

Thanks to which, I was able to finally query CouchDB using Apache Lucene indexing.

4. Before querying I had to insert my custom JSON Design Document, **not new design through the UI**, **neither new view**, but new JSON Document. Essentially hacking CouchDB a little bit with faked design so that could support Lucene search.
   I've used CURL request with the following format

`curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/user14169_slovnik_medical/_design/medical -d @user14169_slovnik_medical.json`

Where the JSON Design Document looked like this:

```
 {
   "_id": "_design/medical",
   "fulltext": {
       "by_meaning": {
           "index": "function(doc) { var ret=new Document(); ret.add(doc.vyznam); return ret }"
       },
       "by_shortcut": {
           "index": "function(doc) { var ret=new Document(); ret.add(doc.zkratka); return ret }"
       }
   }
}
```

5. As an example. Having this search index defined and let's say this type of data in the JSON Documents:

> ```
>   {
>      "_id": "63e5c848fa2211c3b063d6feccd3d942",
>      "_rev": "1-899a6924ed08097b1a37e497d91726fd",
>      "DATAWORKS_DOCUMENT_TYPE": "user14169_slovnik_medical",
>      "vyznam": "End to side",
>      "zkratka": "e-t-s"
>    }
> ```

Then you are easiliy able to achieve queries like this:

```
http://localhost:5984/_fti/local/user14169_slovnik_medical/_design/medical/by_meaning?q=lob~
```

Which returns the expected data:
[image]

The local prefix is because I am running the database on localhost on 1 node and by default couchdb-lucene is connecting to the localhost.

The coolest thing is that you are able to use client API **org.lightcouch** jar library in Java and do some easy calls like this:

```
CouchDbClient dbClient = new CouchDbClient("user14169_slovnik_medical", true, "http", "127.0.0.1", 5984, null, null);

String uriFullText = dbClient.getBaseUri() + "_fti/local/user14169_slovnik_medical/_design/medical/by_shortcut?q=lob*";

JsonObject result = dbClient.findAny(JsonObject.class, uriFullText);

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a search index, you need to create a "view". This is well explained here:  http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/views.html

You can do it right from Futon but you should practice first with a small dataset.

Comment: Is this solution equal to Apache lucene search queries?   with *, fuzzy search etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Search is a Cloudant feature and is not in any current release of CouchDB.

Comment: Best to ask the author.

Comment: Also what about this https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2015/07/31/meet-clouseau-dreyfus/

Comment: It may work with CouchDB 2.0 but that's not released yet.